# Reasons for sticking with TEXT, NTEXT and IMAGE instead of (N)VARCHAR(max) and VARBINARY(max)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, deprecated

TEXT, NTEXT and IMAGE have been deprecated a long time ago and will, eventually, be removed from SQL Server.

However, they are not going to be discontinued right away, not even in the next version of SQL Server, so it's not convenient for my enterprise to transform thousands of columns right away, even if it is using SQL Server 2012.

What arguments can I use to postpone this migration?

I know there are some advantages in using the new types. But I'm strictly looking for reasons not to migrate my data that is already functioning pretty well in the old types.

Comment: There are **no valid reasons** to stick with the deprecated types. They don't offer anything more / better than the newer types that replace them. Go ahead with the migration!

Answer (score 1):

Reasons for **sticking** with TEXT, NTEXT and IMAGE instead of (N)VARCHAR(max) and VARBINARY(max)

1. They currently work
2. Your code works equally on SQL CE as it does on SQL Server

   - argument only good for small DBs
3. There is no current budget to do so
4. Your company is due to fold/product has a set expiry date before the "deprecated feature" turns to "discontinued"
5. You don't care about your job

Reasons for **NOT sticking**

1. They won't work in future
2. It will be stressful to everyone when push comes to shove and you have a short timeframe for fixing
3. You need to code using legacy methods such as TEXTPRT, WRITETEXT, and cast all TEXT/IMAGE to VARCHAR/VARBINARY to do any useful work

Answer (score 0):

Only reason I can think of to not migrate to the new type is that it's easier for the John Assymptoth of today.

If you don't care about the advantages of the new type or the fact that the types you are using will someday be removed, I can't think of a compelling reason to migrate (not that anyone asked but IMHO those are pretty good reasons).  The John Assymptoth of the future might not like it though...

Your employer might be a little upset if you move on to greener pastures and the next guy isn't aware of this issue for some reason.

Comment: How about cases where client drivers, providers and libraries are changed (on the local machine and remote machines) and they no longer support the legacy types? Unless the box is completely isolated and locked down, you can only keep the old stuff intact for so long.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start switching over now. That way you can change one at a time and don't have to change them all at once when this feature is actually discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to be forced into the migration at some later point in time. Your argument now should be that it poses a significant risk to the business to try and change them en-masse; this should be enough to stall the change for the time being. You need to do a proof of concept, figure out how much down time will be needed in total (you'll likely have to break it into batches of changes), create a plan to move to the new data types, and test. And then actually work to move forward. Even the mountain gives way to the river eventually...